# echarts multiple boxplot series on categorical axis

Tags: boxplot, echarts

I am building a layered visualization using overlay of violinplot, jittered scatterplot and boxplot, all using echarts 5.2.1

I have data with multiple categories and I want users to be able to filter data using the legend. Therefore the each category needs to be put in its own series (afaik).

Now I am struggling with putting boxplots from multiple series on the right coordinates on the categorical axis.

In the following codepen the two boxes should appear at the location of the two values of the categorical axis, not side-by-side above only the first value
https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-violin-plot-forked-zxv24f?file=/src/App.js

screen:
[boxplot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh3zF.png)

Is that even possible somehow?
Note: setting `colorBy: 'data'` is not an option for me. I want to be able to filter by dataset group, not by series type.

Here is the complete relevant code of the sandbox inline:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import * as echarts from "echarts/lib/echarts";
import "echarts/lib/chart/boxplot";
import "echarts/lib/component/tooltip";

class App extends Component {
  chartRef = createRef();

  draw = () => {
    const data = [[150, 170, 180, 195, 210]];
    const data2 = [[130, 155, 165, 185, 200]];

    const myChart = echarts.init(this.chartRef.current);

    const option = {
      xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        data: ["Series 1", "Series 2"] // X-axis labels for the two boxplot series
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: "value"
      },
      series: [
        {
          type: "boxplot",
          name: "Series 1",
          data: data // Data for the first boxplot series
        },
        {
          type: "boxplot",
          name: "Series 2",
          data: data2 // Data for the second boxplot series
        }
      ]
    };

    myChart.setOption(option);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.draw();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="chart"
        ref={this.chartRef}
        style={{ width: "800px", height: "400px" }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```